# Create an optional block as a variable

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c-blocks, option-type

I have a simple class where I declare a block as a variable:

```
class MyObject : NSObject 
{
    var progressBlock:(progress:Double) -> ()?

    init() { }
}
```

As far as I understand, if defined this way, `progressBlock` does not have to be initialized in the `init()` initializer

However, when I try to compile I get his error:

```
Property 'self.progressBlock' not initialized at super.init
```

So the question is, how do I create an optional `progressBlock`, so I don't get this error?

Comment: you can create optional var for blocks, but you have to set its value as `nil`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The way you have written it, the compiler assumes progressBlock is a closure that returns an optional empty tuple instead of an optional closure that returns an empty tuple. Try writing it like this instead:

```
class MyObject:NSObject {
    var progressBlock:((progress:Double) -> ())?
    init() {
        progressBlock = nil
        progressBlock = { (Double) -> () in /* code */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: I now do this "var progressBlock:((progress:Double) -> ())?" and it works. Thank you

Comment: Yes. Need that block to be an optional

Answer (score 6):

Adding to connor's reply. An optional block can be written as:

```
var block : (() -> ())? = nil
```

Or as an explicit `Optional`:

```
var block : Optional<() -> ()> = nil
```

Or better yet, with a custom type

```
typealias BlockType = () -> ()

var block : BlockType? = nil
```