# Callback syntax, why do you need brackets for callbacks? (()->Void) vs ()->Void?

Tags: function, swift, syntax, callback

For Swift, I am not sure why you need to surround function variables with extra brackets.

The compiler demands you write them as:
(()->Void)

But what are those surrounding brackets for? To me it seems like I should be able to just write:
()->Void

Do you know what those extra brackets are for?

Example:

```
//callbacks
var backTapCallback:(()->Void)!  //this is valid
var backTapCallback2:()->Void!   //error: Initializer get confused and thinks this variable is not yet delcared when its an optional
```

Comment: In which context? A concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: Updated with an example

Comment: The extra parentheses are only required for an *optional* (or *implicitly unwrapped optional*) closure, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004700/swift-create-an-optional-block-as-a-var.

Comment: The reason your second example fails is that the compiler thinks the `!` applies to the return value `Void`. Parentheses around the whole signature resolve that confusion.

Comment: Gotcha that clears it up thanks!